# Battleships game - Random co-ordinates c++

Tags: c++, random

Ok Ive fixed my code.. I can generate 5 random co-ordinates and save them in my array but I need to make sure co-ordinates do not repeat themselves. I was trying to save each co-ordinate in a separate array and use if statements but I cannot figure out how to do this. Can anybody give me some tips? Here is my code so far..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int *x, *y;
  int a, b;
  int randNum2, randNum;
  char arr[5][5]={{0}};

  srand(time(0));


  x = &randNum;
  y = &randNum2; 


for( a = 0 ; a < 5 ; a++ ){
randNum = (rand() % 5); 
    randNum2 = (rand() % 5);

      arr[*x][*y] = 'S';

   }



   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to format your code so other people can read it and provide a problem description beyond "will not run"

Comment: Thanks, I looked over it again. Ive realised why this wont work.. should I use pointers to check random numbers? I'm fairly new at this so any tips would be great help.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. I've managed to get your code to a point where it will run but I have no idea what the output I'm getting is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons why your code won't work!

```
char arr[5][5] = {{255}};
```

is very likely to do something you did not expect: it initializes only `arr[0][0]` to `255`, all other values being then initialized to `0`.

Thus, the validity range for `x` and `y` is actually between 0 and 4, has you wrote, but `rand() % 5 + 1` gives you a random integer between 1 and 5. So you may either not initialize all the items of the 2-D array, or corrupt memory.

For the remaining code, it is not self-sufficient. What `H` is supposed to be?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, H was meant to be a character to show me when I run the program if I had generated a random co-ordinate

Comment: Thus it should be ``'H'``.

Comment: Thanks, Ive changed the code around but not quite sure how to stop co-ordinates repeating. Take a look at edit above

Comment: Instead of doing a ``for`` loop of length 5, you should do a while loop. You should check the value in ``arr[x][y]`` *before* assigning it. If it's already an ``'S'``, don't increment ``a``. Otherwise, it's a new position, and you can go safely.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int x, y;
    char arr[5][5]={{255}};
    srand(time(0));

    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 5; y++) 
        {
            int randNum = (rand() % 5) + 1; 
            int randNum2 = (rand() % 5) + 1;    
            if(x==randNum && y==randNum2)
                cout<< (arr[x][y] = 'H');
            else
                cout<< (arr[x][y] = 255);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs this gives are like

```
�����
�����
��H��
�����
�����

�����
��H��
���H�
����H
�����
```

...and so on, sometimes with no H.

Now you tell me what this is supposed to be.

Comment: Im trying to generate 5 random co-ordinates. The H was simply meant to show me if I had generated them. I can see now that I will have to place the code                                                       int randNum = (rand() % 5) + 1; 
int randNum2 = (rand() % 5) + 1;   outside the loop and use pointers to check the if statements